# Are there rank N lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Suppose I have a simple GADT.

```hs
data Expr a where
  Int' :: Integer -> Expr Int
  Fun :: Text -> Expr a
  (:*) :: Expr (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
```

Now, I can define the following traversal over it:

```
transform :: Applicative f => (forall b. Expr b -> f (Expr b)) -> Expr a -> f (Expr a)
transform f (a :* b) = (:*) <$> transform f a <*> transform f b
transform f v = f v
```

The type looks curiously a lot like `Traversal` from lens. However, not exactly, it's higher ranked.

I can still define «conventional» `set` and `over` though. `view` is more complex, there are some obstacles to avoid (impredicative types), but doable.

Does this construction have a name? Is it supported in any way by the existing lens libraries or researched?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but just additional relevant pointers:

- Your `transform` function also appears to be a case of [`traverse` from rank2classes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes-1.5.1/docs/Rank2.html#t:Traversable).
- I've found it to be more useful if the function would also get a witness for the child expression types, resulting in [hypertypes' `htraverse`](https://github.com/lamdu/hypertypes/blob/master/src/Hyper/Class/Traversable.hs#L74)